# Prevent raw JSON from displaying in the browser

Tags: json, node.js

I've created a PhoneGap app that gets database updates from a node.js server. The latter is very simple (my node chops are very basic, I'm only a hobbyist) with some basic routing and then sending raw JSON back to the user. At the moment if you hit the URL with a browser it is displayed, which has been useful for debug purposes, but I now need to prevent this.

The data isn't sensitive at all. There is no user data sent or received. But the content is something that has had time and effort put into it, and I'd rather not show it to the world.

But by the same token I don't want to have to implement a heavy-handed solution. Encryption isn't really necessary (but I concede it may be the best option).

What would be your suggestions for  simple/light ways of not displaying the JSON? I saw one idea using a ´display: hidden´ div but this doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: Why don't you want it to be displayed? I don't understand.

Comment: @Strikeskids The app is a compact drug database for nurses and doctors. A lot of hard work went into both sanitizing the data (reading drug data sheets, and picking out the key info) as well as the laborious task of entering it as JSON. I guess I'd rather not have it on display for someone to just take.

Comment: @Strikeskids But all the info is in the public domain. I've just rationalized it and made it easy to consume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option if you want to secure your data is to use an encryption. It seems that you find encryption to be "heavy-handed" but that really is the best way. If you don't want to encrypt it, you could try checking the user-agent and implementing a custom user-agent into your app. If that's worth implementing, however, then encryption is also worth implementing.

Comment: +1 for encryption (https or otherwise). -1 for header checking, as anyone who is already sniffing the traffic could just as easily duplicate the headers used in the sniffed request.

Comment: Thanks both - any suggestions for Node.JS encryption libraries that are easy to get to grips with?

Comment: Obviously header checking does not prevent people from sniffing requests, but it does prevent random bots on the internet from discovering it.